# Do I thaw frozen sea food before cooking?

Tags: freezing

Do I need to keep prepared frozen sea food frozen before cooking?  I purchased cod, shrimp, and scallops.

Comment: It depends on the type of products you have. Can you please give us more details about the items? You say they are 'prepared' - how so?

Answer (score 2):

If this is just raw seafood, and not already prepared, heat and serve meals, keep frozen until use.  Thaw (ideally in the refrigerator), then cook. If they are meals already prepared (with other ingredients), simply follow the package directions.  Many of these items are cooked from frozen.

Answer (score 0):

**I thaw frozen seafood in a bowl of hot tap water.**

Some frozen stuff like Lean Cuisines are meant to go freezer to microwave.  I don't mean those.  I mean bags of frozen fish or shrimp, cooked or uncooked.

If it is in plastic, I leave it in plastic.  If it is not, I put it in a plastic bag.  If there is enough frozen seafood to cool the water down, I put in more.  I like the hot water because the fish thaws fast and will not get overcooked, and we always have hot water.

Thawing it in the refrigerator is theoretically a good idea except I either don't think of it the day before, or I do and it is still not thawed and it goes into the hot water anyway.

Cooked cocktail shrimp for stirfry are an exception.  I think the ice in those bags of cooked cocktail shrimp have shrimp flavor and so the whole thing goes in after the stirfry is done, and the hot vegetables thaw the shrimp and the shrimp cools down the vegetables and I don't have to wait as long to eat.

Answer (score -1):

Scientifically, cooking any frozen food directly should waste some of its value and change the taste and seafood is not an exception.

#### Reference:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_food#Quality
2. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5fa4/7b747878f686a658134760b7811b0e2172d1.pdf
3. http://www.adafsa.gov.ae/English/Awareness/topics/Pages/ThawingFrozenFood.aspx -Look at *Cook it frozen method*

Comment: What you mean by "waste some of its value" is not clear.  Freezing, and cooking from frozen, are very common practices.

Comment: @moscafj I have said **directly** without thaw in the room temperature.

Comment: What do you mean by "waste some of its value"? For that matter, what do you mean by "scientifically"? Some explanation and documentation of your claim would improve your answer.

Comment: @Sneftel References are added.

Comment: @moscafj References are added.

Comment: @SaidbakR you still haven't defined the word "value". Your first link is about the thawing process, doesn't say anything about the cooking. The second one is about beef. The third one specifically mentions that the method is ideal for ready-to-eat frozen food. If this is what the OP bought, then your own link contradicts your suggestion, while the two others are irrelevant.

Comment: @rumtscho the third link clearly states that it is not suitable to cook some items including fish with that way: "*This method is ideal for frozen vegetables, ready-to eat frozen food, small cuts of meat, chicken and fish. Large cuts of meat ,fish and chicken should not be cooked while frozen.*

Comment: Yes, I read that part. The question is somewhat ambiguously formulated, but to me, "prepared frozen seafood" sounds like "ready-to-eat frozen food", not like a "large cut of [...] fish".